# Parsing webpage with beautifulsoup to get dynamic content

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the following page
http://www.lyricsnmusic.com/roxy-music/while-my-heart-is-still-beating-lyrics/26925936 for the list of similar songs.

The list of similar songs is not present in the page source but is present when I use 'Inspect Element' in the browser.
How do I do it??
Current code:

```
url = 'http://www.lyricsnmusic.com/roxy-music/while-my-heart-is-still-beating-lyrics/26925936'
request = urllib2.Request(url)
lyricsPage = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(lyricsPage)
```

The code to generate the links is:

```
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    s = p.find('a', { "class" : 'title' }).get('href')
```

Which methods are available to do this??

Comment: The page uses the [Last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api) to load that data.

Comment: The [`application.js` script](http://www.lyricsnmusic.com/javascripts/application.js) is not minified, I suggest you go read it and work out how to use the same API for yourself instead of scraping a third-party website. Look for the http://ws.audioscrobbler.com URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is handled probably by some ajax calls so it will not be in the source,

I think you would need to "monitor network" through developer tools in the browser and look for requests you are interested in.

i.e. a random picked request URL from this page:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?api_key=73581584905631c5fc15720f03b0b9c8&format=json&callback=jQuery1703329798618797213_1380004055342&method=track.getSimilar&limit=10&artist=roxy%20music&track=while%20my%20heart%20is%20still%20beating&_=1380004055943

to get/see the response enter the above URL in the browser and see the content of the response.

so you need to simulate the requests in python and after you get the response you have to parse the response for interesting details.

Comment: On Windows, I suggest using Fiddler[1] to help reverse engineer the AJAX calls:

  [1]: http://fiddler2.com/features

Comment: You may also have success using [web driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) to control an actual web browser, letting it handle the ajax calls for you.

Comment: I was able to make API calls to Lastfm and get the list of similar songs directly and build their urls on the original site. Thanks everyone

Comment: @kevgathuku . How did you do that? Can you share your code?